# [Desktop: command not found error when trying to run .desktop file in terminal

Tags: command-line, python, launcher, python3, .desktop

I am trying to create a launcher for a python code that I am working on.
Here is the code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=START_TRIALS
Exec=/home/arielm123/Desktop/mira/start_terminal_and_run.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=archive/mm_trajectories.png
Name[en_CA]=START_TRIALS.desktop
```

When I simply press on the icon, the program does not even launch and seems to immediately crash, and when I try to run it in terminal I get the following error:

```
line 1: [Desktop: command not found
```

I also have all the permissions necessary for the file.

I can't seem to find a clear answer as to what that error message means and how to fix it. Any advice would help :)

Comment: Is your `/home/arielm123/Desktop/mira/start_terminal_and_run.sh`executable? If not make it so (using `chmod +x`)

Comment: @kanehekili 
Yes it is, when I simply run /home/arielm123/Desktop/mira/start_terminal_and_run.sh in the terminal it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a desktop file in Ubuntu you should use the following pattern:

create a file in `home/.local/share/applications/mydesktopfile.desktop` or as sudo in `/usr/share/applications`.

The "mydesktopfile.desktop" (name it as you like,but keep the .desktop) should contain the following elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/home/arielm123/Desktop/mira/start_terminal_and_run.sh
Name=Start Terminal and Run
Comment=My Terminal Program
Icon=gnome-terminal
Categories=GTK;GNOME
```

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great. Thanks for the feedback